# How to get variable from different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm trying to do is get a search term from one function getRandomVideo() and use it in a jQuery statement, so for example, get beethoven from the variable searches and use it as the search term to get back JSON information and append it to a div. I know next to nothing about jQuery so any help would be great thanks :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function getRandomVideo() {
                        var videos = [
                            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/kiTO7c_qeZs',
                            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Hfv00eqoI',
                            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cdZYQB5ONE',
                            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/i1gE3nyQnKg',
                        ];
                        var titles = [
                            'Beethoven - Music, Love and Wine',
                            'Mozart String Serenade No.13',
                            'Beethoven Sonata No. 31 in A Flat Major',
                            "Debussy - Children's Corner",
                        ];
                        var images = [
                            "url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')",
                            "url('Assets/mozart.jpg')",
                            "url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')",
                            "url('Assets/debussy.jpg')",
                        ]
                        var searches = [
                            'beethoven',
                            'mozart',
                            'beethoven',
                            'debussy',
                        ]
                        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
                        var video = videos[rand];
                        var title = titles[rand];
                        var image = images[rand];
                        var search = searches[rand]; 

                        document.getElementById("songTitle").innerHTML = title;
                        document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = image;
                        var htmlVideo = document.getElementById("randomVideo");
                        htmlVideo.src = video;
                        htmlVideo.onload=null;  
                        return search
                    }
                    getRandomVideo();

                    $(document).ready(function(){

                            // Im not sure what to do here to get it to run when the page starts                           
                            // Get the value from our getRandomVideo()
                            var searchTerm = getRandomVideo();

                            var url = "http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=jja10ssv4950uh65&encoding=json&zone=newspaper&sortby=relevance&q=" + searchTerm + "&s=0&n=5&include=articletext,pdf&encoding=json&callback=?";

                            /*  
                            *   Perform the search using jQuery's getJSON method
                            *   Requires the search URL
                            */  
                            console.log(url);

                            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

                                $.each(data.response.zone[0].records.article, function(index, value) {
                                    $("#output").append("<p>" + value.articleText +"</p>");
                                });
                        });
                    };
                </script>
```

Comment: It's all to do with scope mate, will add an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea as to how to accomplish this...

```
var getRandomVideo = (function(){

        var _videos = [
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/kiTO7c_qeZs',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Hfv00eqoI',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cdZYQB5ONE',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/i1gE3nyQnKg',
        ];

        var _titles = [
            'Beethoven - Music, Love and Wine',
            'Mozart String Serenade No.13',
            'Beethoven Sonata No. 31 in A Flat Major',
            "Debussy - Children's Corner",
        ];

        var _images = [
            "url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')",
            "url('Assets/mozart.jpg')",
            "url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')",
            "url('Assets/debussy.jpg')",
        ];

        var _searches = [
            'beethoven',
            'mozart',
            'beethoven',
            'debussy',
        ];

        return {

            videos: function(){ return _videos; },

            titles: function(){ return _titles; },

            images: function(){ return _images; },

            searches: function(){ return _searches; }
        };

    })(); // this is the module pattern FYI

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * getRandomVideo.videos().length);

    var video = getRandomVideo.videos()[rand];
    var title = getRandomVideo.titles()[rand];
    var image = getRandomVideo.images()[rand];
    var search = getRandomVideo.searches()[rand]; 

    document.getElementById("songTitle").innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = image;
    var htmlVideo = document.getElementById("randomVideo");
```

In javascript, everything including variables are scoped by function so any variable declared inside a function such as...

```
function myFunction()
{
    var a1 = "something";
}

var test = a1; // a1 would be undefined as it is out of scope of `myFunction()` so test would be too of course
```

By using the module pattern, you can expose properties/functions within the `return{};` statement. NB: the underscores are just to identify private functions/objects etc ;)

Also if you were to do the below, you would be able to access `a1` as it would cascade into global scope as it has not been declared...

```
function myFunction()
{
    a1 = "something"; 
}

var test = a1; // a1 would be "something"
```

But I wouldn't suggest this... for a number of architectural reasons :-/